# Jenkins: You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-sdk-tools, gradlew

I have downloaded the `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219` and apply `$ANDROID_HOME/sdk` in Android SDK root at Configure System in Jenkins.

My error is:

```
 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK 
 components:
 [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2, Android SDK Platform 25].
 Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and 
 complete the installation of the missing components using the Android 
 Studio SDK Manager.
 Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one 
 workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-
 licenses.html
```

I have seen a lot of tutorials that i need to run `./sdkmanager --licenses`
 at `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`. But the real problem is i dont have BIN in my adt-bundle. Here is my directory: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Gradle\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools`. The bin folder is missing and i dont have it. Did i download the wrong sdk tools? I also run the SDK Manager, unfortunately the bin folder is missing in tools.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION IN JENKINS JOB:
I just invoke the gradle script and add tasks: packageDebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved.

Steps:

1. Download sdk tools in android studio website
2. Create a folder then extract the sdk into that folder
3. Go to tools/bin directory
4. Go to CMD in that directory then type ./sdkmanager.bat --licenses
5. Just press y everytime they ask you for the licenese